# I can't remove Mongodb

Tags: apt, dpkg, 21.10, mongodb

When I exec

> sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*

I got a lot of errors like this  :

> E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-server_5.0.6-2_amd64.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mongodb-org-server_5.0.6-2_amd64.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mongodb-org-server_5.0.6-2_amd64.deb'

Comment: How did you install Mongo in the first place? Has a previous installation attempt failed? Were files deleted from a previously working installation? A bit more detail will be needed to point you to a working solution 

Comment: Maybe it is a Flatpack or a Snap.

Comment: @matigo , I installed Mongodb and it was working. After that I don't know what happened then I couldn't run '' Mongod''. Then I was looking for a solution for my problems and I deleted some Mongo files from /var/log/mongodb and /var/lib/mongodb. After that I got I lot of errors. My laptop is full now, it has 200+ Gb free space. And system errors